# Executing Server Side JavaScript via c# MongoDb Driver v2

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Is there an alternative solution for executing adhoc JS server-side via the C# 2.0 driver?

Reading the docs on MongoDb, it appears that eval() has been deprecated, and it's also recommended that business logic not be uploaded to the server as server-side scripts, which means I shouldn't upload my own functions and use IMongoDatabase.RunCommandAsync().

Off-hand, I'm not certain I need this capability for upcoming projects.  So, I'm just making myself aware of the options available.

Comment: Why do you *need* this for a project? Why can't that problem be solved in code (where it, IMHO, should be solved)? There's usually a relatively easy way to avoid code in the database, maybe we can work that out.

Comment: One use case I can think of would be scheduling and running of maintenance scripts without the Mongo CLI in a hosted environment.